# UDT migrations in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm looking for concrete recommendations on how to approach user defined types migration in cassandra and I can't find anything conclusive. Does anyone have experience changing such types when they're in use? If so, what's the best strategy to approach the problem? A UDT cannot be modified when in use which makes it really difficult to migrate. What are the necessary steps to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

There are only [2 operations possible for UDTs in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlAlterType.html):

- Adding a new field
- Renaming the field

In reality, I would suggest just to add new fields to the UDT, and don't rename existing fields - when you add a new field, this could be done incrementally in application, while renaming will require deployment of the new version at time of change, and this is not always possible.

Comment: This implies no fields will ever be removed or changed in any way. This might lead to a mess with time.

Comment: Unfortunately it’s a limitation of Cassandra... Together with other limitations about schema changes. At some point of time you’ll need to create new UDTs, new tables and migrate data